# Regex to find anything after 4th Slash

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I need your help in writing regex statement for the string
`/AB/PS/EUR/ES_Electr_ML_TB`

I need to detect the anything written between 4th slash (/) and the first underscore (_), meaning that in the above example, the output should be `ES`, as it is between 4th slash and then the first underscore.

Comment: Please tag with the programming language you are using, and also include any code you have already tried.

Comment: I am creating this with SQL, i believe the regex will be similar for any PL.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: 15.0 is version

Comment: Do you need to _extract_ "ES"?  Or simply _detect_ that the syntax is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `substring_index()` to get the desired result:

```sql
select
  substring_index(substring_index('/AB/PS/EUR/ES_Electr_ML_TB', '/', -1), '_', 1)
```

It will always look at the following characters after the last slash (/), and then at the characters before the first underscore (_). So in this example, the query output would be `ES`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @test NVARCHAR(50)  = '/AB/PS/EUR/ES_Electr_ML_TB'
select RIGHT(SUBSTRING(@test,0,CHARINDEX('_',@test,0)),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@test,0,CHARINDEX('_',@test,0))),1)-1)
```

That's my solution only using "standard" SQL functions

```
SUBSTRING(@test,0,CHARINDEX('_',@test,0))
```

Gives you `/AB/PS/EUR/ES`

and

```
CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@test,0,CHARINDEX('_',@test,0))),1)-1
```

tells us how many chars we need to go from the right side.

Then we just use a regular RIGHT to get the needed chars

Answer (score 0):

U can use this code it is working on ORACLE.

```
select col,regexp_substr(col,'([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])',1,4) as d  from 

(   select '/AB/PS/EUR/ES_Electr_ML_TB  ' as col from dual 
    

)
```